# ASP.NET - Warn user about unsaved changes before leaving page or switching tabs

Tags: jquery, asp.net, tabs

I have an application developed in ASP.NET where a main screen is presented with different tabs (i'm using JQuery tabs btw: https://jqueryui.com/tabs/). Each tab points to a different partial view. Two of these tabs contain a group of input fields to be filled with a Save button for each of them. I want to warn the user in case he changes one of these inputs and does not save.

This is my Javascript code:

```
var somethingChanged = false;

    $('#formDadosPessoais input').change(function () {
        somethingChanged = true;
    });
    $('#formDadosPessoais select').change(function () {
        somethingChanged = true;
    });

    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function (e) {
        if (somethingChanged)
            return "Voçê efectuou alterações nos seus dados pessoais e não guardou as alterações.";
        else
            e = null; // i.e; if form state change show warning box, else don't show it.
    });
```

I tested it and it works when i logout, close the page or refresh. However, it doesn't work when i switch tabs. For instance, if i change the inputs in tab 1 and switch to another tab, the warning should pop up.

How can i tweak the code to cover this scenario?

Here's the HTML for my tabs in case if it's necessary:

```
<div id="tabs" style="margin-top:20px;">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Personal Data</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Inquiry</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Candidature</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-4">Documents</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-5">Declaration</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            @Html.Action("Index", "PersonalData")
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            @Html.Action("Index", "Inquiry")
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
            @Html.Action("Index", "Candidature")
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-4">
            @Html.Action("Index", "Documents")
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-5">
            @Html.Action("Index", "Declaration")
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what does @Html.Action("Index", "Declaration") generate ? a link ? if yes then you can bind $('#tabs div a').on("click", function(){somethingChanged = true;}); to it to set your variabl before leaving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching a tab doesn't trigger `beforeunload` so you will also need to hook into the tab api's [`beforeActivate` handle](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-beforeActivate)

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
  beforeActivate: function( event, ui ) {
      if (somethingChanged && !confirm("Voçê efectuou alterações nos seus dados pessoais e não guardou as alterações.")
        return false;
        //can ignore else as they said ok to change
  }
});
```

### Edit:

Modified example to explicity call a confirm box before returning false. Returning false cancels the activate event so the tab does not switch. Returning true is the default behavior and will switch tabs.

Comment: I tried this (with the message in the return instead of false since returning false doesn't allow me to switch tabs) but the warning doesn't pop up when i switch tabs. Furthermore, i get a bug where the contents from other tabs appear on tabs where they shouldn't appear.

However, if i leave the "somethingChanged" condition empty, this bug doesn't happen.

Comment: Also, if i leave the "beforeActivate" handle empty, i still get that bug where the contents from other tabs are displayed in tabs where they shouldn't be displayed.

Comment: return false prevents the tab switch. This is a barebones example and you need to modify it to your needs. You should throw up an alert to see if the user is ok with the switch, usually done via a confirm box. If they confirm then you return true. If they hit cancel you return false.

Comment: Now the warning pops up but for some reason, the contents from other tabs continue to appear in tabs where they shouldn't appear. In other words, they're all mixed.

Comment: Also, is there a way for the warning to only show when switching from the first tab to another tab instead of showing up for any tab switch?

Comment: Is the warning message the same as the contents of the `confirm` part of the code or is it an actual error? `confirm`boxes are a way to ask user input before proceeding. You can add a check to see what tab triggered the change and to what tab you are going. Look at the api documentation for the jquery ui tabs.

Comment: Okay, i used ui.newTab.index() and it did the trick. Now the warning popup message (which is the same as the confirm contents of the code) only appears when i'm switching from the 1st tab to any other tab. Now how can i fix the error where the tab contents are broken and mixed (e.g. contents from tabs 2 to 5 appearing on tab 1, contents from tabs 3-5 appearing on 2, etc)?

Comment: I managed to fix it by putting the function inside "$(function () {});". Now the tab contents are displayed properly and the warning works. Anyway, thanks for the help! =)